# How to use multiple independent conditional styles on same div in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna know how to use multiple independent conditional styles on same div in react js.  For one condition we can use ternary operator.  But i want to use different independent conditions.

For example: I have a textarea and I have three buttons with Bold, italic and underline.  I want if i click on any button will do their respective task.

this is working fine

```
<textarea
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={ this.state.bold ? {fontWeight: 'bolder'} : {fontStyle: 
        'normal'}}
        />
```

but this is not:

```
<textarea
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={ this.state.bold ? {fontWeight: 'bolder'} : {fontWeight: 
        'normal'}}
        style={ this.state.italic? {fontStyle: 'italic'} : {fontStyle: 
        'normal'}}
        />
```

How to have multiple independent conditional styles in reactjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add two styles to one div.Maybe not a good choice, you can use both style and className:

```
style={ this.state.bold ? {fontWeight: 'bolder'} : {fontWeight: 
        'normal'}}
className={ this.state.italic? {fontStyle: 'italic'} : {fontStyle: 
        'normal'}}
```

And you can also try this:

```
setStyle (){
    let styles = {}
    if (this.state.first === 'first'){
        const firstStyle = {
           ...
        }
        styles = Object.assign(styles,firstStyle)
    }
    if (this.state.second === 'second'){
        const secondStyle = {
            ...
        }
        styles = Object.assign(styles,secondStyle)
    }
    if (this.state.third === 'third'){
        const thirdStyle = {
            ...
        }
        styles = Object.assign(styles,thirdStyle)
    }
    return styles
}
....
<div style={this.setStyle()}>Test</div>
```

Comment: what if I have three conditions or more than that? like bold, italic, underline and hyperlink

Comment: @anant I have changed my answer, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 5):

You can make this:

```js
const handleStyleButton = (condition) => {
    if (condition) {
     return {
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 10,
        border: 'none',
        margin: '.5em',
        minWidth: 60,
        cursor: 'pointer'
     }
    }
    return {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 10,
        border: 'none',
        margin: '.5em',
        minWidth: 60,
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }
};
```

with html

```html
<button style={handleStyleButton(true)} />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can nest ternaries.

Note that this can get pretty unreadable super fast.

```
style={
  this.state.bold
    ? this.state.italic
      ? { fontWeight: "bolder", fontStyle: "italic" }
      : { fontWeight: "bolder", fontStyle: "normal" }
    : this.state.italic
      ? { fontWeight: "normal", fontStyle: "italic" }
      : { fontWeight: "normal", fontStyle: "normal" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in css.

```
 <style>
        .class1{
        }
        .class2
        {
        }
     </style>
```

in react use those classes based on the condition  and use nested it if you want
.store the class in state

```
{this.state.case1?class1:class2}
```